# How do I write coding using while loops and if statements in jes?

Tags: python, jes

How do i write a code in JES program for cropping a specific image with a give coordinates and how do i write a code in JES program for pixelating an image using while loops and if statements?  Also, how do i write code in JES program for blur heavy and reduce jaggies if it is a 5x5 grid?

Comment: Could you be more specific ? What do you mean by 'how do I write code' ?

Comment: First of all, there are three questions there. Second of all, you didn't even try to look this stuff up, did you?

Answer (score 0):

1. Start by downloading and installing JES [from googlecode](http://code.google.com/p/mediacomp-jes/)
2. Read [*Introduction to Programming with JES*](http://alumni.cs.ucr.edu/~titus/JesIntro.pdf) and work through the examples
3. [Google for more information](http://www.google.com/search?q=JES+program+for+cropping)